# cURL on local WordPress site returns: Error 6 (Could not resolve host)

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, curl, guzzle

I have a local WordPress installation running at: https://catalogue3.test.

Note that all `.test` domains should resolve to `localhost`, as I use [Laravel valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet). When I execute the following code in my Laravel project however, I get an exception as shown below.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', "https://catalogue3.test", ['verify' => false]);
```

> ConnectException
>
> cURL error 6: Could not resolve: catalogue3.test (Domain name not
>   found) (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

When I run the command below in the terminal, the WordPress page is displayed.

```
curl https://catalogue3.test/ --insecure
```

Comment: Did you add catalogue3.test to your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Nop, Laravel valet use DnsMasq

Comment: Same issue here with a Laravel application running under Laravel Valet (no Wordpress). Have you find a fix ?

Comment: @MaximeFreschard nop I didn't have any success :(

Comment: @MaximeFreschard Found a solution !

Comment: @cmac your solution is the good one, please put it as an answer, and I will accept it. I just don't understand why I should add it to /etc/hosts using DnsMasq

Comment: I'm not sure, but DnsMasq says this "Local DNS names can be defined by reading /etc/hosts, by importing names from the DHCP subsystem, or by configuration of a wide range of useful record types."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

> ***ip*  catalogue3.test**

to your **/etc/hosts** file

Answer (score 6):

I tried to add the domain to hosts and I tried to change dns in network settings, [this answer](https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/736#issuecomment-502431248) is what worked for me.

> Quick way to check if this is your problem is to do: `curl --version`
>   and `php --ri curl`
>
> The versions should match. If they don't it's probably because brew
>   has installed curl-openssl. This can be removed by doing:
>
> `brew uninstall curl-openssl --ignore-dependencies`
>
> Maybe there's a way to configure the installed curl-openssl properly -
>   I've not investigated this yet.

Comment: I would have never figured this out. This worked though!

Comment: Works like a charm. After runnig `brew uninstall curl-openssl --ignore-dependencies` you need to restart valet with `valet restart`.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this adding catalogue3.test to `/etc/hosts`, even if I was using `DnsMasq`, and in theory, I wouldn't need it.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (on macos) I had to add 127.0.0.1 as the first DNS server option in my WiFi settings.

Some useful info here too: https://github.com/laravel/valet/issues/736